# How can I access UrlWriter url/path generators from a model's class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I want to generate urls from a model's class method. I've done this before from an instance method by simply including `ActionController::UrlWriter` -- I tried including this in the instance definition scope and also the class definition scope, to no avail.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # only works for instance methods
  # include ActionController::UrlWriter

  class << self
    # results in this error: undefined method `default_url_options' for Class:Class
    # include ActionController::UrlWriter
    def my_method
      return user_sprockets_url(:thingy => 'blue')
    end
  end    
end
```

Comment: it occurs to me that `ActionController::UrlWriter` methods are usually included in a class, so they become part of that class's instance methods. so trying to make them available to class methods... could be trouble. (and impossible)

Comment: http://slaive-prog.tumblr.com/post/7618787555/using-routes-in-your-model-in-rails-3-0-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ModelURL
  include ActionController::UrlWriter
end

class User
  @url_generator = ModelURL.new
  class << self
    def admin_path
      @url_generator.send :admin_path
    end
  end
end
```

> ruby-1.9.1-p378 ?> User.admin_path
>
> ```
> => "/admin"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Sweet!

a little refactoring..

```
class ModelURL
  include ActionController::UrlWriter
  @@singleton = ModelURL.new
  class << self
    def singleton
      @@singleton
    end
  end
end
```

usage...

```
ModelURL::singleton.send :user_sprockets_url, :thingy => 'blue', :host => DOMAIN
```

Comment: Great refactor, just needs to be "ModelURL::singleton" rather than ::generator